# Android SeekBar Issue in ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-seekbar, getview

I have an issue while using seekbar in listview, Seekbar's seek starts getting updated on a button click but the problem occurs when we have more than  one seekbar in list
Suppose i have three seekbar's in my list if i click on second or third seekbar, first(in the list) seekbar's seek starts getting updated always.

Please Help me in resolving this issue.

Below is my Code:

Listview in xml :

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstMessages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relSendMessage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relRecipient"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_shadow"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" android:stackFromBottom="true" tools:listitem="@layout/message_left"/


Adapter Class Code :
    public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCompletionListener{
        Context context;
        TextView txtmsg;
        ImageView imgSender ,playaudio;
         TextView txtSender;
         TextView txtDate;
         VideoView videosender;
         SeekBar seekbar;
         MediaPlayer mp;
         private boolean bVideoIsBeingTouched = false;
         private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        public ChatAdapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            data = arraylist;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }


          @Override
          public int getItemViewType(int position) {

           return position;
          }
@Override
        public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            resultp = data.get(position);

            if (convertView == null) {

                int res = 0;
                if(resultp.get(Tab2.CHAT_MSG).equals("/AUDIO/")&&resultp.get(Tab2.CHAT_TYPE).equals("outgoing"))
                {

                    final String path=resultp.get(Tab2.PATH);
                    res = R.layout.audioleft;
                    LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                     convertView = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);
                      txtSender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSender);
                      playaudio = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                      seekbar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);



                      playaudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                                getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                 mp = new MediaPlayer();
                              mp.setOnCompletionListener(ChatAdapter.this);

                                try {
                                    playaudio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_btn_pause);
                                    mp.setDataSource(path);
                                    mp.prepare();
                                    mp.start();

                                   seekbar.setProgress(0);
                                    seekbar.setMax(100);

                                    // Updating progress bar
                                    updateProgressBar();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }   



                            }   

               });
                      txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);



                     }
}
            else
            {

            }
return convertView;
        }
}
public void updateProgressBar() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
        }   

        /**
         * Background Runnable thread
         * */
        private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                   long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

                   // Displaying Total Duration time

                   // Displaying time completed playing
                   );

                   // Updating progress bar
                   int progress = (int)(getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
                   //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
                   seekbar.setProgress(progress);

                   // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
                   mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
               }
            };

audioleft.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Sender Ipsum"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@color/sinch_purple"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="14:54"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSender"/>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtSender"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="12dp"

                >
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
              android:thumb="@drawable/sthumb" 
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
            />

           <!--   android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler" -->




<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/songProgressBar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_btn_play" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with my timer , it does not stops after completion i stopped the timer after every seekbar completion and problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new listeners and affect it to the seekbar each time you inflate a new one in getView()

```
seekbar.setOnXXXListener(new XXXListener(){

    public void onSeekXXX(){
        //do your thing about this seekbar...
    }
)};
```

EDIT :

You should really concider using the ViewHolder patern : [External link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: I have tried this with viewholder pattern too,but this issue is not getting resolved.I dont know why it always starts updating first seekbar item.